# Java type error between array element and charAt variable

Tags: java, arrays, indexing, reverse

I have created an integer array where the elements are the indexes of the characters of a string that I want to modify via reverse order.

For example, 
string: `text = "java is fun"`
array: `array = [0, 6, 8, 9]`
Wanting to reverse the order the characters: 'j' 's' 'f' 'u'
Expected output = "uava if sjn"

I'm trying to use a for loop to run through array and modify the characters at that index, but there seems to be a type error, where `text.charAt(array[j])` is expecting a variable but is receiving a value instead. `unexpected type required: variable found: value`

Is there another way to go about this?

Here is my code:

```
for (int j = 0; j < array.length/2; j++)
{
     int el = array[j];
     text.charAt(el) = text.charAt(array.length - j -1);
     text.charAt(array.length - j -1) = el;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set a new value to a position with `text.chatAt(i)`, with this you can only read values.

Take a look at `text.toCharArray()` and after changing with `for` loop `String.copyValueOf(charArray)`